# How to multithread in Grizzly

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, heroku, grizzly

I'm implementing a Java RESTful webservice on Heroku.  Currently my entry point looks like

```
public class Main
{

    public static final String BASE_URI = getBaseURI();

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        final Map<String, String> initParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        initParams.put( "com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "services.contracts" );
        initParams.put( "com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true" );

        System.out.println( "Starting grizzly..." );
        SelectorThread threadSelector =
        GrizzlyWebContainerFactory.create( BASE_URI, initParams );

        System.out.println( String.format( "Jersey started with WADL available at %sapplication.wadl.", BASE_URI,
                BASE_URI ) );
    }

    private static String getBaseURI()
    {
        return "http://localhost:" + ( System.getenv( "PORT" ) != null ? System.getenv( "PORT" ) : "9998" ) + "/";
    }

}
```

where the `initParms` contains RESTful services being hosted.  I understand that GrizzlyWebContainerFactory.create() returns an instance of `ServletContainer` (`SelectorThread`), but how would I multithread the returned `threadSelector` such that multiple `SelectorThread`'s can handle the incoming requests under one process (aka web dyno)?  The reason is to increase performance of a single dyno in handling requests.

Any suggestions appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call:

```
SelectorThread.setSelectorReadThreadsCount(int)
```